# JavaCV Convert color HSV2RGB very slow

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, javacv, iplimage

I have recently started with JavaCv using Android for camera preview image processing.

Basically, I take the camera preview, do some processing, convert it to HSV to modify some colors, and then I want to convert it to RGBA to fill a bitmap.

Everything works normally, but quite slow. In order to find the slowest part I made some measurements, and to my surprise found this line:

```
cvCvtColor( hsvimage, imageBitmap, CV_HSV2RGB); //<-- 50msecs
```

where **hsvimage** is a 3-channel IplImage, and **imageBitmap** is 4 channel.image. (The conversion is good and leaves the alpha channel to 255, giving an opaque bitmap as expected)

Just for comparison, the following two lines only take 3msec

```
        cvCvtColor(yuvimage, bgrimage, CV_YUV2BGR_NV21);            
        cvCvtColor(bgrimage, hsvimage, CV_BGR2HSV);
```

(**yuvimage** is 1 channel IplImage, **bgrimage** and **hsvimage** are 3 channel IplImages)

It seems as if the first conversion (HSV2RGB) isn't so much optimized as others. Also tested it with a 3-channel destination image, just in case, but with the same results.

I would like to find a way to make it as fast as BGR2HSV. Possible ways:

- Find if there is another "equivalent" constant to CV_HSV2RGB which is
  faster
- Get direct access to the H-S-V byte arrays and make my own "fast" conversion
  in C.

Any idea to solve this issue will be welcome

**--EDIT--**

All this is happening with a small 320*240 image and running on a Xiaomi Redmi Note 4. Most of the operations such as converting color from RGB to HSV take less than 1 msec. Canny takes 5msec, Floodfill takes about 5 or 6 msec. It is only this conversion HSV2RGB which gives such strange results. 
Will try to use OpenCV directly (not JavaCV) to see if this behaviour disappears.

I was using an old JavaCV version (0.11) Now I have updated to 1.3 and results are nearly the same

```
...
long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
cvCvtColor(hsvimage, imageBitmap, CV_HSV2RGB);
Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Time:" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)); //<-- From 45 to 50msec
Log.w(LOG_TAG,"Channels:"+imageBitmap.nChannels()); // <-- returns 4
```

I can fill a 32bit/pixel android bitmap with the result

```
Mat mim4C= new Mat(imageBitmap);
Mat mhsvimage = new Mat(hsvimage);
long startTime**strong text**=System.currentTimeMillis();
CvtColor(mhsvimage, mim4C, CV_HSV2RGB);
Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Time:" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)); //<-- From 45 to 50mse
IplImage iim4C=new IplImage(mim4C);
Log.w(LOG_TAG,"Channels:"+iim4C.nChannels()); // <-- returns 3!!!
```

In this second case, if I try to fill a 32bits/pixel android bitmap (after converting back mim4C to IplImage), it crashes since it has 3 channels

Comment: "imageBitmap is 4 channel.image" -- but your conversion code is `CV_HSV2RGB`, and RGB has 3 channels. Since the channel count doesn't match, OpenCV would realloc the `Mat` (verified in C++). Your claim of the contrary seems rather suspect in that light.

Comment: Not sure to understand. I think it keeps on being a 4-channel image but the conversion only uses the first 3 ones. Otherwise, I would see wrong results when copying the result to an Android ARGB8888 bitmap. Also, as I say in the post, the same happens (conversion is slow) when I do the conversion into a 3-channel IplImage.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the severe speed discrepancy you mention. The "HSV2RGB" conversions are roughly 15% slower than "RGB2HSV" (2.4ms vs 2.1ms for a 1024x1024 image). | Could you please specify the OpenCV version and the specific hardware you run this on? Also provide a [complete piece of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can demonstrate and reproduce the issues you mention (print the number of channels of the destination `Mat` as well as the timings to console).

Comment: I was using JavaCV 0.11 (quite old) and have just upgraded to JavaCV 1.3, which wraps OpenCV 3.0, according to what I have read. If I use the cvtColor(...) working with Mat, which is from the C++ interface, then you are right and reallocates memory to 3 channels. But it is slow anyway. Using cvCvtColor(IplImage,IplImage,int), does NOT reallocate the memory and leaves 4 channels. All this is with JavaCV. Do you get these results with JavaCV or with OpenCV own Java wrapper? Editing post to better illustrate what I mean